# newline character on text area

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom field called Current_Address__c which is of datatype textarea.

I need to populate this field in the format below. ie a newline char after street and another newline after zip.

street
City state Zip
Country

The values of city state zip country etc are been taken from contact object. I dont want to use this as a formula field. So i need to populate it in my controller and display it on my VF page.

I am trying to add a newline char by using the code below

```
this.customobj.Current_Address__c = currentStreet + '\\n ' + currentCity + ' ' + currentState  + ' ' + currentZIP  + '\\n ' + currentCountry ;
```

i had also used  \n instead of \n.

It still show the field in one line instead of 3 lines

EDIT

I got this working  using the following code. I would accept mathews answer as it would work with outputfield.

```
                currentAddress = currentStreet;
            currentAddress += '\r\n';
            currentAddress += currentCity + + ' ' + currentState  + ' ' + currentZIP ;
            currentAddress += '\r\n';
            currentAddress += currentCountry;
```

This works only if you use +=.
not sure why this happens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the issue, you have two escape character slashes (`\\n`), but only one is needed because the slash in `\n` does not need to be escaped in this context.

Also, Salesforce saves a new line as `\r\n`. Try this:

```
this.customobj.Current_Address__c 
    = currentStreet + ' \r\n' 
    + currentCity + ' ' + currentState  + ' ' + currentZIP  + ' \r\n' 
    + currentCountry;
```

This method works when using an **`<apex:outputfield>`** with an sObject field.

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!myCustomSObject__c.Address__c}"/>
```

If you're using a different Visualforce Component, it won't work. Visualforce renders the new line in HTML when using a `<apex:outputtext>` Component, but HTML ignores new lines. If you use a `<br/>` tag, Visualforce renders it as `&lt;br/&gt;`.

The best solution I could come up with for rendering a variable that has new lines in it (rather than an sObject field) is to use a disabled `<apex:inputtextarea>`.

```
<apex:inputtextarea value="{!myAddress}" disabled="true" readonly="true">
</apex:inputtextarea>
```

Comment: Im having the same problem. I tried \r\n , \n , \\n and even <br /> and non of them worked!

Comment: What type of tag are you using to display the data? `<apex:outputfield>` worked for me.

Comment: I cant use outputfield because I do dynamic binding. I get this error
value for <apex:outputField> is not a dynamic binding!

Comment: Like this: `<apex:outputfield value="{!Widget__c.Address__c}">`.

Comment: I got this error:   Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!fetchedData}'. <apex:outputField> can only be used with SObject fields.

Comment: I edited my answer, please see above. `<apex:outputfield>` won't work unless it is used with an sObject field.

Comment: Mathew.. i had tried a similar  code before i posted here. i had used /r/n and with single / . It didnt come out correct. it was all coming up correct. As raymOnd had used i was also using outputtext. I finally code got it working on outputtext. i am edit my quesstion to post the code i had done

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had the same problem, I wanted to reder the new lines in an 
The solution that I found was this, it is a little tricky but it works:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(textVariableThanContainsNewLines), '\\n', '<br/>')}" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller

```
public List<String> getLetterLines() {
    if (letterBody == null) {
        return new List<String>();
    }
    return letterBody.split('\n');
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!letterLines}" var="letterLine">
    <apex:outputText value="{!letterLine}" /><br />
</apex:repeat>
```

Have fun!

Answer (score -3):

value="Remarks : {!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(textVariableThanContainsNewLines), '\r\n', '
')}"

Comment: Some things to think about before answering: 1) Your answer should **add** new information to the post, not just duplicate someone else's, 2) You should explain why/how the answer solves the problem, and 3) You should format your answer nicely (put code in code blocks).